# Mobile application bug-ish behavior

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app, ios-app

This has been annoying me for a couple years but it has never changed. Same situation persists on all Stack Exchange sites.
On the mobile app, when I choose `Tags` from drop down menu, I get a list of tags and I choose one, and I get the list of questions relevant with that tag and that's all good. Now, I choose one question and when I am done with it, I go back using the back arrow on the upper left corner (or ◀ on my phone) it goes all the way back to the tags list. Wouldn't it make more sense for it to go back to the list questions with related tag? I might be a bad user with bad taste, just asking. (I've used both IOS and Android during these couple of years, same goes for both)

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Please see [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/289905).

Comment: The mobile apps are no longer supported, sorry.

Comment: Opps, didn't know that. Thanks! @MartijnPieters